# tensor, symmetric, exterior power of a module over a PID

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, homological-algebra, noncommutative-algebra

Let $R$ be a PID and $M\cong R^r\!\oplus\bigoplus_{i=1}^s\!R/Ra_i$. Denote the tensor, symmetric, exterior power of $M$ by $T^nM=\bigotimes_{k=1}^nM$ and $S^nM= T^nM/\langle x_{\sigma1}\!\otimes\cdots\!\otimes x_{\sigma n}\!-\!x_1\!\otimes\cdots\!\otimes x_n; x_1,\ldots,x_n\!\in\!M, \sigma\!\in\!S_n\rangle$ and $\Lambda^nM=T^nM/\langle x_1\!\otimes\cdots\!\otimes x_n; x_1,\ldots,x_n\!\in\!M; x_i\!=\!x_j\text{ for some }i\!\neq\!j\rangle$.

By the rules $R^r\!\otimes\!A\cong A^r$, $A\!\otimes\!(B\!\oplus\!C)\cong (A\!\otimes\!B)\!\oplus\!(A\!\otimes\!C)$, $R/I\otimes R/J\cong R/\langle I,J\rangle$, we conclude 
$$T^n\!M\cong R^{r^n}\!\oplus\bigoplus_{k=1}^n \bigoplus_{1\leq i_1,\ldots,i_k\leq s} (R/R\gcd(a_{i_1},\ldots,a_{i_k}))^{r^{n-k}}.$$
What is the formula for $S^nM$ and $\Lambda^nM$ (free rank and torsion coefficients)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the following:

1. $S^n(M \oplus N) = \bigoplus_{p+q=n} S^p(M) \otimes S^q(N)$, likewise for $\Lambda^n$.
2. $S^n(R/I) = T^n(R/I)$
3. $\Lambda^n(R/I)=0$ for $n>1$

Comment: I haven't checked the formulas (and also won't do it). I don't think that they will be useful. It is really more important to know the general techniques how to compute symmetric and exterior powers.

Comment: In general $S^2((R/I)^3) \cong (R/I)^6$. There are $6$ partitions $2=a+b+c$, and each summand gives you $R/I$.

Comment: Explicitly, $R^6 \cong S^2(R^3)$ corresponds to the basis $\{x_1^2,x_2^2,x_3^2,x_1 x_2,x_1 x_3,x_2 x_3\}$ of $S^2(R^3)$ when $\{x_1,x_2,x_3\}$ is a basis of $R^3$.

Comment: Ok, so $R=K[t]$ and $M\cong R^2\oplus (R/Rt)^3$ should imply $S^2M\cong R^3\!\oplus\!(R/Rt)^{12}$ and $\lambda^2M\cong R\!\oplus\!(R/Rt)^9$, right?

Comment: Yes, that's right!